# How to obtain the count of letter in a string using python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to take a string like "bbbbjjpppppbb" and return a string like b4j2p5b2 using python programming language.
Basically the letter followed by the count of letters.

Comment: Please add your current script.  This looks like a homework question to me.

Comment: What if the characters are mixed such as bbjjppbbjjbb?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code:

```
s = "bbbbjjpppppbb"
from itertools import groupby
groups = groupby(s)
result = [(label, sum(1 for _ in group)) for label, group in groups]
lst = []
for i in result:
    delim = ""    # for joining, delim is used
    res = delim.join(map(str, i))
    lst.append(res)
output = ''.join(lst)
print(output)
```

output:

```
b4j2p5b2
```

Comment: But it's not like preferred result `b4j2p5b2`. It should be in a straight line.

Comment: @Shayan This is very simple. I tried to solve the `main` part but now I have completed the code.Thanks for attention

Comment: Also, you should delete commented commands in case of readability. Many print commands have been commented on. If they aren't necessary then you should remove them.

Comment: Thanks for helping with this everyone.
Really appreciate this.